# How should I get mentioned strings from my messge?

Tags: android, regex

I don't know if this is the right question or not but I want to get string from special character.

Example:

```
Hi this is #myFirst post on This #StackExchange.
```

I want to output `#myFirst` and `#StackExchange`.

I tried

```
(.*#[a-zA-Z_0-9])+\\w+
```

However, it gives me whole string.

Comment: Chack [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114200/find-the-words-start-from-a-special-character-java).

Comment: (.*#[a-zA-Z_0-9])+\\w+ i have make like this but it will give me whole string

Comment: @AvinashRaj it is get only me #myFirst. rather then i want both  #myFirst and #StackExchange

Comment: you need to use  a while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are capturing the whole string because you have `.*` pattern in the beginning.

Just use

```
#[a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

[This is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/vQ6aB6/1) that shows what this regex will match.

Also, please note that this regex will only let you match English script based hashtags. You can use `#\w+` (in Java string, `#\\w+`) to match Unicode strings, too, as in Android, [`\w` shorthand class also matches Unicode letters](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

> Note that these built-in classes don't just cover the traditional
>   ASCII range. For example, `\w` is equivalent to the character class
>   `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}]`.

Some [sample code](https://ideone.com/MgVJpH):

```
import java.util.regex.*;
...
String str = "Hi this is #myFirst post on This #StackExchange.";
String rx = "#[a-zA-Z0-9_]+";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Output:

```
#myFirst
#StackExchange
```

Answer (score 1):

You can String tokenizer for this. if your string has# every time.

```
StringTokenizer token= new StringTokenizer(YourString, "#");

   while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
      String value = token.nextToken(); 
      System.out.println("value from token" + value);
   }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This does not yield expected results ([tested in Java environment](https://ideone.com/1sVR3x))

Comment: you can add "#" to your value after 2 loop. and you can get your expected result.